# Remove specific values in one specific column based on the index values

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I  have the following table where **hour is index**:

```
Hour         date        plant1     plant2    plant3 ....
07:00:00    2019-06-23    22.1      22.8      21.4
07:03:00    2019-06-23    31.7      33.1      12.4
07:06:00    2019-06-23    11.1      12.5      11.4
07:09:00    2019-06-23    17.6      19.34     22.1
...
08:26:00    2019-06-23    11.1      12.5      11.4
08:40:00    2019-06-23    17.6      19.34     22.1
08:50:00    2019-06-23    11.1      12.5      11.4
08:59:00    2019-06-23    17.6      19.34     22.1
09:06:00    2019-06-23    11.1      12.5      11.4
09:09:00    2019-06-23    17.6      19.34     22.1
```

I want to change the values of plant 1 to whitespace or null between the hours 07:10 to 08:51  only for so it will look like this:

```
Hour         date        plant1     plant2    plant3 ....
07:00:00    2019-06-23    22.1      22.8      21.4
07:03:00    2019-06-23    31.7      33.1      12.4
07:06:00    2019-06-23    11.1      12.5      11.4
07:09:00    2019-06-23    17.6      19.34     22.1
...
08:26:00    2019-06-23              12.5      11.4
08:40:00    2019-06-23              19.34     22.1
08:50:00    2019-06-23              12.5      11.4
08:59:00    2019-06-23    17.6      19.34     22.1
09:06:00    2019-06-23    11.1      12.5      11.4
09:09:00    2019-06-23    17.6      19.34     22.1
```

I have tried to do this like this:

```
df.loc['plant1'] = df.loc['plant1'].mask((df['Hour'].between(time(7,10,0),time(8,51,0)),''))
```

But i'm getting keyerror for plant1 (and also not sure that this is the best/correct way to do that).

**My end goal: to be able to remove values in specific column for specific index locations based on index location.**

Clarification : I need the hour to be the index only (without the date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible convert hour and date column to datetimeindex use [`DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time.html) for indices between times in strings form and then set values of column by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with indexing `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df.index.astype(str))

idx = df.index.indexer_between_time('07:10:00','08:51:00')

df.loc[df.index[idx], 'plant1'] = np.nan
print (df)
                           date  plant1  plant2  plant3  ....
2019-06-23 07:00:00  2019-06-23    22.1   22.80    21.4   NaN
2019-06-23 07:03:00  2019-06-23    31.7   33.10    12.4   NaN
2019-06-23 07:06:00  2019-06-23    11.1   12.50    11.4   NaN
2019-06-23 07:09:00  2019-06-23    17.6   19.34    22.1   NaN
2019-06-23 08:26:00  2019-06-23     NaN   12.50    11.4   NaN
2019-06-23 08:40:00  2019-06-23     NaN   19.34    22.1   NaN
2019-06-23 08:50:00  2019-06-23     NaN   12.50    11.4   NaN
2019-06-23 08:59:00  2019-06-23    17.6   19.34    22.1   NaN
2019-06-23 09:06:00  2019-06-23    11.1   12.50    11.4   NaN
2019-06-23 09:09:00  2019-06-23    17.6   19.34    22.1   NaN
```

In your solution if `Hour` is index use `index.to_series()` because [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) not working with `DatetimeIndex` yet:

```
df['plant1'] = df['plant1'].mask((df.index.between(time(7,10,0),time(8,51,0))))
```

> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'between'

```
df['plant1'] = df['plant1'].mask((df.index.to_series().between(time(7,10,0),time(8,51,0))))
print (df)
                date  plant1  plant2  plant3  ....
07:00:00  2019-06-23    22.1   22.80    21.4   NaN
07:03:00  2019-06-23    31.7   33.10    12.4   NaN
07:06:00  2019-06-23    11.1   12.50    11.4   NaN
07:09:00  2019-06-23    17.6   19.34    22.1   NaN
08:26:00  2019-06-23     NaN   12.50    11.4   NaN
08:40:00  2019-06-23     NaN   19.34    22.1   NaN
08:50:00  2019-06-23     NaN   12.50    11.4   NaN
08:59:00  2019-06-23    17.6   19.34    22.1   NaN
09:06:00  2019-06-23    11.1   12.50    11.4   NaN
09:09:00  2019-06-23    17.6   19.34    22.1   NaN
```